# pycrypto with multiple users in virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, paramiko, pycrypto

I'm using Paramiko (which depends on PyCrypto) on Windows in a virtual environment.

Because I'm on Windows, I don't have a C compiler by default, so I got the windows executable from XXX, and installed it using:

```
workon myenv
easy_install pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe
python myscript.py
```

And everything worked for me.

Now my colleague (Steve) would like to use the same program, so he does:

```
workon myenv
python myscript.py
```

and it fails with "ImportError: no module named Crypto".  Which is odd.  What is odder is that if Steve easy_installs the PyCrypto module, he can use it, *but I can't*.  The library only seems to work for the person who installed it.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `virtualenvwrapper`, which creates virtualenv directory in `.virtualenvs` inside users' home directory by default. ([`WORKON_HOME`][1])

Users' home directories are not shared. So other user cannot use your virtualenv.

Make a virtualenv in a directory that your friend can access.

```
virtualenv /some/shared/virtualenv-dir
```

And let other user activate it:

```
/some/shared/virtualenv-dir/activate
```

---

If you want to use `virtualenvwrapper`, you and other users need to set `WORKON_HOME` environmental variable to a shared directory. (Not sure this also apply for win32 version of virtualenvwrapper you're using)

Comment: good thinking (I forget that we're using virtualenvwrapper).  sadly, we both have WORKON_HOME=c:\python-envs in our environments.  I also had Steve go directly to the scripts directory and "activate", but we're getting the same problem.